# How to convert 2d array into format that keras+LSTM needs

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I have a `5000 by 9` 2d numpy array of features `trainX` which are the features of a time sequence. I also have a 1d numpy array of floating point feature labels `trainY`.  This is exactly the format you would need for `scikit-learn` for example.

I would like to use these with keras+LSTM. This is my code at present:

```
NUM_EPOCHS = 20
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(8, input_shape=(1, window_size)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

However this doesn't work as keras needs `trainX` in a different format it seems.  I have read the manual but I can't understand what this is exactly.

How can I convert my data into a format that keras will accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format is `(samples, timeSteps, features)`

How many sequences do you have? It sounds like one sequence of 5000 steps, is that right?

Then the format is `(1,5000,9)`.

The labels should also be `(1,5000,1)`, if you have one label per time step. (Then use `return_sequences=True`). Otherwise labels are `(1,1)`.

---

Optionally, you may want to split your single sequence in many segments, in a classical sliding window case, for instance, where you'd have many samples with less time steps, such as `(4998,3,1)`, supposing you want a 3-step window. Then the labels should follow: `(4998,1)`.

Comment: Why would you add a sliding window if you are using lstm rnns? Doesn't that already take the history into account?

Comment: Yes, they do. It's not necessary, but it's an option, and lots of tutorials show that (which I also think is not the best to do, but maybe, depending on your purposes, it may serve).

Comment: For what applications would you not have 1 in the first axis?

Comment: Any application where you have more than one sequence. Imagine you've got 2000 customers, and you have for every month in two years how many units they bought of product1, product2 and product3. - `(2000,24,3)`

Comment: Thanks. So I just need the numpy code to convert from a 2d (5000,9) feature array to a (1,5000,9) one it seems.