# How to fit 2D pandas array into Keras LSTM layer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I have a 2D array(pandas) which is of time series with 3180 rows and each row with 8 columns(array) as features. I am trying to train an LSTM layer

```
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
print (X_train.shape)
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(LSTM(units=128, input_shape=(1, len(X_train), x.shape[1])))
```

as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228270/how-to-convert-2d-array-into-format-that-keraslstm-needs). But error comes up like,

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LSTM` expects a 3D array as input, so `input_shape` shape should be of length 2...

Assuming that `X_train.shape` is `(3180, 8, 1)`, this should work:

```
LSTM(units=128, input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
```

Comment: Please let me know, how can we increase the accuracy of any Keras+LSTM network where time-series prediction is taking place.

Comment: If that solved your problem, select the answer as correct. About the accuracy, you should probably start a new question.